# Solubilizing ability of dichlorobenzenes

Tags: solvents

I am trying to understand why 1,2- and 1,3-dichlorobenzenes are such good solvents, able to solvate many organic compounds known to be hard to get dissolved.

Any precise answer?

It has something to do with dipolar moment and Hansen's diffusion parameter I think.